# Call Mono C# Compiler

Tags: c#, mono

For calling MS C# compiler there is `CSharpCodeProvider` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx)

but how do I call the Mono compiler?

I want to know if there was any errors after compilation.

Comment: btw, the best place to ask help about Mono is mailing lists http://mono-project.com/Mailing_Lists

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used Mono, but a quick Bing turned up the following [Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider](http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?tlink=37@ecma%3a3727%23CSharpCodeProvider%2f) in the Mono documentation, is it possible that Mono implements the functionality targeting the Mono C# compiler.

Comment: Yep, it should be exactly the same.  Don't change anything, just use Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider and Mono will do the right thing.

Answer (score 4):

Mono has a better approach available (which should be provided in .NET 5 probably),

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-10.html

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at MonoDevelop. It's full featured IDE for the Mono project, speaking of C#, F# and others. You can create a project, generate the classes, paste your source and it'll take care of everything.

Speaking of the compiler:
It's called mcs if you exported mono to your PATH. `man mcs/mcs --help`.

Comment: `mcs` is non-generic C# compiler i.e. for .NET 1.x. `gmcs` is for 2.0+. It's better to man it

Comment: While abatishchev was 100% correct at the time, 'mcs' is now (as of Mono 2.10) a runtime independent version of the Mono compiler without these limitations. The old 'mcs' (which targeted the .NET 1.1 profile) has been retired.

Answer (score 0):

Probably using `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` from Mono will call Mono's implementation of Microsoft C# compiler which is the same as Microsoft's.

To call Mono specific features of C# compiler use `Mono.CSharp.dll`